# which .net components does my application need?

Tags: .net, deployment, desktop-application

I built a vb.net desktop application. it works beautifuuly on my pc. I created an installer and gave it to a co-worker to run. The program does not work.

Question: How can I figure out which .net components i need to provide along with my application?

Thanks

Comment: check the error log/.net exception/event viewer for .net errors which point to missing/undefined namespaces.

Comment: How did you create your installer? What components have you added to your application? Does your colleague have the same version of the .Net framework installed?

Comment: Does he have the .net franework installed at all?

Comment: he does have the .net framework installed, though not necessarilly the same as me. However, i need to be able to isntall this on machines that don't necessarily have any .net components

Answer (score 6):

You should create a Setup Project and add your main Project as a required component.
The Setup project should be able to detect all managed dependencies automatically and you can decide to add them to your programm folder.

Here is a quich tutorial I found with Mr. google: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vishnuprasad2005/SetupProjects12022005022406AM/SetupProjects.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and dirtiest way to do this is to create a [ClickOnce installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31kztyey(v=VS.90).aspx).  Just set it up to create an installer for "a UNC path or file share."  IIRC it will take care of any bootstrapping that needs to be done.  This assumes, of course, the dependencies he needs are all standard .NET components.

If you are referencing assemblies that are not standard, you'll need to select the reference, open the properties window, and set "Copy Local" to true.  They will then be included in the ClickOnce installer.